# Cannot read content of Docker environment file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I specified the env file *accounts.env* in the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    env_file: accounts.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=***
      - MYSQL_USER=***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  migrations:
    image: micheleminno/db-migrations:latest
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

This is the env file:

```
accountSize = 28

user1screenName = ***

...
```

and here's an example of Node.js code where I read some environment variables defined in the env file:

```
...

if (credentialsIndex < process.env.accountSize) {

...
```

My problem is that the object process.env doesn't contain the variables I've specified. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried removing the spacing around the `=` in the `.env` file? I believe this is why your variables aren't showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things here. If i run the below compose file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    env_file: accounts.env
    image: node
    command: node -e 'console.log(process.env);'
```

The output is

```
web_1  | { PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
web_1  |   HOSTNAME: 'd207b3388203',
web_1  |   'user1screenName ': ' tarun',
web_1  |   'accountSize ': ' 28',
web_1  |   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL: 'info',
web_1  |   NODE_VERSION: '8.3.0',
web_1  |   YARN_VERSION: '0.27.5',
web_1  |   HOME: '/root' }
```

As you can see the `accountSize` will get a space as you added after a `=` and also the name of the environment is `accountSize` with a space at the end. Which means you would need to access it using `process.env["accountSize "]`. Anyways fix the environment file, no space before and after.